# Why does the Jupyter Notebook output is displaying arrays from right to left

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Jupyter Notebook, writing some python code using numpy library.
For some reason, The output of arrays (as well as lists and strings) are displyed from right to left.

[image: example of an output of array in jupiter]

Comment: It is always better to post code instead of Image

Comment: @kelvin But the problem seems to be specific to the Jupyter Notebook GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your system set up for Hebrew? Note that the `:[4] In` is on the right as well. That may trigger array output to be right-to-left.

From [this comment on github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10980):

> Press Ctrl-Shift-F to bring up the command palette. Search for 'rtl'
> and select 'toggle rtl layout'. It should switch around.
>
> If the first language selected in your browser is Arabic or Hebrew, it
> currently selects RTL by default. CCing @samarsultan in case that
> needs refining.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.
Now it works fine.
My browser was set to hebrew and by changing to english it fixed the problem.